# find matching array and return the key using php

Tags: php, arrays, matching

I have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => name2 surname
            [1] => email2@email.com
            [2] => 834502034
            [3] => image url3
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => name3 surname
            [1] => email2@email.com
            [2] => 7648484886
            [3] => image url3
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => name0 surname
            [1] => email0@email.com
            [2] => 56783658658
            [3] => image url0
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => name1 surname
            [1] => email1@email.com
            [2] => 7648484886
            [3] => image url1
        )

)
```

youll notice that some of the values are the same and may only have a single difference in value.

I need to find out if another single array matches any on of the sub arrays and return the key.

the array I would match against is not multidimensional:

```
Array
            (
                [0] => name1 surname
                [1] => email1@email.com
                [2] => 7648484886
                [3] => image url1
            )
```

How do I find out if my single array is found within the main array and return the KEY?
Ive tried using array_diff_uassoc with a callback which returns the non matching key => array and I guess I could then match the count of both results to see if there is a difference, but I still need the key of the matched array. The array I am comparing against will always have the exact values [0],[1],[2] and [3].

Comment: You may want to look at the array_filter() function and array_walk() function. See here http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php and here http://pt.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`array_search`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) will do that, taking advantage of [how comparing arrays for equality works in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#example-118) (which means that the order of items inside each sub-array *and* in the array you provide as the search target must be the same!):

```
$master = array(
    array('surname', 'foo'),
    array('surname', 'bar'),
);

$key = array_search(array('surname', 'baz'), $master));

if ($key === false) {
    echo "not found";
}
else {
    echo "found, key is $key";
}
```

Comment: If I understood correctly OP does not have predefined array that must be searched.

Comment: @PLB: That's what I understood as well. But there's nothing here that requires a predefined array to work.

Comment: @Jon - once again, exactly what I had hoped for... theres a PHP function for just about everything! (p.s.please tell me what an OP is?)

Comment: @Innate: Original Poster -- in this case, you. :)

Answer (score 0):

Since it is an exact match you can use [array_search](http://php.net/array_search) for this:

```
$key = array_search($array_to_find, $array_to_search_in);
```

Comment: also correct - had to accept the first correct answer though. thanks Emil, Jons answer was also more explanatory.